# Pass argument of call to another function in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like a way to take the argument to a `call` invocation in a Makefile rule and pass that to a builtin function, in this case `wildcard`.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
MODULE_OBJS = $(patsubst %.cc, %.o, $(wildcard $(1)/*.cc))

lib%.a: $(call MODULE_OBJS, %)
    @echo $@ : $^
```

In this case I would expect `make libfoo.a` to print a list of .o files corresponding to the .cc files found under foo/, but nothing is printed. The parameter is getting there because if I append `$(1)` to the end of MODULE_OBJS the value of `%` gets printed, but it seems to be lost when getting passed into `wildcard`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand that make will execute `$(call MODULE_OBJS, %)` *before* it has even begun building the dependency tree, you cannot accomplish this with a pattern rule. You could use `eval` hackery but there's a case to made against trying to be too clever with make.

Something like the following is easy enough to maintain

```
MODULE_OBJS = $(patsubst %.cc, %.o, $(wildcard $(1)/*.cc))

libfoo.a: $(call MODULE_OBJS, foo)

lib%.a:
    @echo $@: $^
```

but after wrestling with clever ways of generating library and binary dependencies I prefer simply listing them explicitly.

Comment: Yes.  Very much yes.  It's almost never a good idea to generate dependencies, and Make is one of the few cases where ‘use the whole language’ is bad advice.  Make is a language for automating boring/confusing things; it's not a language for being clever in.

Answer (score 1):

I got what I wanted with some hacking of the eval rule:

```
EXCLUDE_MODULES = obj
MODULES = $(filter-out $(EXCLUDE_MODULES), $(patsubst %/, %, $(wildcard */)))

define MODULE_RULE
lib$(MODULE).a: $(patsubst %.cc, obj/%.o, $(wildcard $(MODULE)/*.cc))
    @echo $@ : $^
endef

$(foreach MODULE, $(MODULES), $(eval $(MODULE_RULE)))
```

This allows you to call `make libfoo.a` and get out a list of all the .o's corresponding with the .cc's in that subdirectory.

For those curious, I uploaded a complete example [here](https://github.com/moof2k/make/blob/master/2_libs/Makefile).

The [Metaprogramming Make](http://make.mad-scientist.net/the-eval-function/) articles were a useful resource here.